# Xamarin.Auth getting disallowed_useragent error [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, google-signin, xamarin.auth

I was trying to implement login with *Google* and *Facebook*. I have successfully implemented *Facebook* login with *Xamarin.Auth* but in the *Google Login* I am getting error **disallowed_useragent**, I know Google has changed their policy and will not allow the login using `WebView` but is there any other way to implement `Login with Google` in `Xamarin.Forms (Portable)`?

[image]

Thank You.

Comment: I have same issue.  Any one can help us.

Answer (score 1):

It's a new Google restriction, they do not allow using their login interface in embedded webviews anymore. Therefore you can implement authorization for your app in "Native Views" - external browsers (chrome tabs, safari etc). They will return result back to your app.

The working example for Google is here:
[Authenticating Users with an Identity Provider](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/)